# What is the meaning of this statement?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

In this book 'The Prevention of Suicide in Prison' I would like to know meaning of this statement:

It also became clear that within this setting all behaviours came at a
price (such as reading/writing other people’s letters) and anything that
could be used as currency could be a massive advantage for a prisoner.
Therefore, although it was explained that some prisoners would elect to
have another prisoner read the study information sheet for them as a means
of illiterate prisoners gaining access to information, it was suggested that
researchers should be aware of this ‘cost’ for a prisoner when designing
studies. Linked to this need to be aware of the ‘prison economy’ was the
warning that researchers must carefully think through the use of incentives, as some prisoners would play act the part of an eligible participant to
access the incentives because they could be valuable currency. Thus without sufficient awareness of the setting, researchers may not understand
that key participants may not be able to access studies without a ‘cost’ and
that some eager participants may not be suitable for the study:

Male #2: The negatives is [sic] that you are offering carrots for
somebody like monkeys wanting peanuts you have to get
somebody who is interesting in what you are doing.

Male #1: Yeah if you give too much then you will [get] folk coming
along for what they can get out of it more rather than
[. . .]

Male #2: Yeah I was given information for months and I got stuff
every time I went in do you know what I mean? I would
read a book and tell them what they wanted to hear.

Male #1: If there was a good screw you were on a couple of mars
bars and whatever everyone would be bloody suicidal.
(SURG focus group)

> If there was a good **screw** you were on a couple of mars bars and
> whatever everyone would be bloody suicidal.

Thank you

Comment: It would help if you included the sentences around this one for context. Also, which part of the given sentence is causing you problems?

Comment: Looks like it's missing punctuation, because it doesn't make sense. A screw is a prison guard in prisoners' slang; Mars bars are confectionery items.

Comment: Mars bars are sometimes used as bribes in prisons. Also, "Mars bar" is rhyming slang, rhyming with "scar", but normally you say the first word only. (But then, "Mars" on its own might stand for "Mars and Venus" which means...  But I'll spare your blushes.) I can get no further with the meaning of the whole sentence without tangling with various online *tea-leaves* who want me to subscribe. As KillingTime said, we need context.

Comment: The context can be found in Google Books (link in my answer) but I'm afraid I'm not about to spend the time to transcribe it into the question!

Comment: I think the word ***screw*** is out of place here. It's not easy to parse it as the slang term for ***prison officer*** that one might expect, given the context, but the sentence makes perfect sense if we assume ***screw*** should have been ***chance*** (if the standard treatment for being suicidal  in prison was to be given a couple of consolatory candy bars, obviously ***every*** prisoner ***would*** claim to be suicidally depressed! :)  OR there should be another ***and*** before ***everyone*** (if a "good" guard ***was*** on duty doling out candy, everyone ***did*** claim to be suicidal).

Comment: @FumbleFingers If you search ‘screw’ in the Google book link in my answer you will see a snippet of a non-viewable page which seems to suggest that the term ‘screw’ covers both uniformed and other staff, so including the staff who run programmes for inmates.

Comment: For some reason I thought the word was AmE, but it appears to be mainly BrE. Some context, and a link would be appreciated...

Comment: @KillingTime I put the text more complete. My problem is the practical meaning of the word screw in this paragraph.

Thank you

Comment: @Spagirl I read your answer, it was very helpful. I appreciate your time and thank you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @Stuart F Thank you for your explanation. It was helpful.

Comment: @Old Brixtonian I put the text more complete. And thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @Cascabel link is:
https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NOtzCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT162&ots=JvmTniMzJq&dq=%22If%20there%20was%20a%20good%20screw%20you%20were%20on%20a%20couple%20of%20mars%20bars%20and%20whatever%20everyone%20would%20be%20bloody%20suicidal%22.&pg=PT162#v=onepage&q=%22If%20there%20was%20a%20good%20screw%20you%20were%20on%20a%20couple%20of%20mars%20bars%20and%20whatever%20everyone%20would%20be%20bloody%20suicidal%22.&f=false
I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of the quote, found here at [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=NOtzCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT162&ots=JvmTniMzJq&dq=%22If%20there%20was%20a%20good%20screw%20you%20were%20on%20a%20couple%20of%20mars%20bars%20and%20whatever%20everyone%20would%20be%20bloody%20suicidal%22.&pg=PT162#v=onepage&q=%22If%20there%20was%20a%20good%20screw%20you%20were%20on%20a%20couple%20of%20mars%20bars%20and%20whatever%20everyone%20would%20be%20bloody%20suicidal%22.&f=false) is that inmates who are not eligible for certain programmes may enrol on them in order to access benefits offered for enrolment, if the benefits are a tradeable commodity.

In this instance being discussed the programme is a Suicide Prevention Programme and the incentive for enrolment is two Mars Bars. As Mars Bars are valuable currency, lots of people will declare themselves to be contemplating suicide in order to enrol and get the Mars Bars.

'Everyone would be bloody suicidal' is a metaphorical expression of the fact that many would *pretend* to be suicidal.

In the Google book link you will also see a snippet of a non-viewable page which seems to suggest that the term ‘screw’ covers both uniformed and other staff, so including the staff who run programmes for inmates.

Comment: Your explanation was very helpful. I would like if you could comment on the practical meaning of the screw in this paragraph.

Thank you.